# How to select element in template based on model?

Tags: angular

I have the following type of data returned from server: `let response: RegistryGeneric[]`:

```
interface RegistryGeneric {
   id: number;
   name: number;
}
```

I want to mark if item `RegistryGeneric` is selected by user. For that I created extended interface:

```
interface RegistryGenericUI extends RegistryGeneric {
   selected: boolean;
}
```

And method that allow to set selected property:

```
public setSelected(registry: RegistryGeneric) {
   registry.selected = true;
}
```

I wonder is it correct way to do that or batter create `new Map<RegistryGeneric><boolean>()` inside component where to store selected `RegistryGeneric`?

How do you solve this in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this is more of a 'Typescript' question rather than 'Angular'? Unless I am mistaken, you should be able to solve it all with only one interface.

One way would be to add a `selected?:boolean` property to your first interface. This would make the property optional (so you won't get an error if the `RegistryGeneric` you get back from your server does not have it). Note, though, that using the optional properties (marked with `?`) is generally NOT the way to go. It's easy if you're starting with Typescript, but the language offers better possibilities.

One better way, but I'm still learning it myself, would be to use the [Typescript utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), such as `Omit`. This would allow you to use the typing to the maximum of its functionality. You'd get most control over your data and get the best support from your IDE. In this case for example you could set up your interface with three properties, and then your server would return objects of type `<Omit<RegistryGeneric, 'selected '>>`. It makes the code harder to read but if for some reason you're not using your types properly, the compiler will show errors early on.

**EDIT**: as I said, I'm still learning the second approach myself so take it with a grain of salt. I saw `Omit` being used in cases where e.g. you have an `id` in your Typescript interface, which you can use for example to delete an item, but you don't want to pass the `id` when you create a new item (because the `id` is generated by the server)